# tmux two bind-key

Tags: tmux

I try make a bind-key for tmux with two keys, like

```
bind-key Vs split-window "command00"
```

I try with this in my `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key V split-window "~/.tmux/tmux-v.sh"
```

and this script `tmux-v.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                              
read -n 1 input                                                                          
case $input in                                                                           
    s ) tmux split-window 'vim +VimShell' ;;                                             
    S ) tmux new-window 'vim +VimShell' ;;                                               
    * ) tmux new-window "vim" ;;                                                         
esac
```

this work, but this solution split the window.

I try with `command-prompt` and `run-shell` but is necessary press `ENTER`

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bind V send-keys "~/.tmux/tmux-v.sh" \; send-keys "Enter"
```